# php HybridAuth Google suddenly crashes into Invalid Credentials

Tags: google-oauth, hybridauth

Two years ago I integrated my website to Facebook, LinkedIn, Twitter and Google+ using php HybridAuth 2.9.1.

In the spring of the year, 2018 Facebook login stopped functioning, because of their new stricter checks and/or new API version. I got rid of that problem by adding the necessary new configurations in my Facebook developer console and upgrading my HybridAuth to 2.11.0.

Having done this, I checked that also Google login functioned OK. It functioned the next day too, and the day after that. But then Google login stopped functioning, and has not recovered since. It gives me this error:

Google returned an invalid response:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array( 'error' => stdClass::__set_state(array( 
'errors' => array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'domain' => 'global', 
'reason' => 'authError', 'message' => 'Invalid Credentials', 'locationType' 
=> 'header', 'location' => 'Authorization', )), ), 'code' => 401, 'message' 
=> 'Invalid Credentials', )), ))' in 
/var/www/html/test/hybridauth_2.9.1/Hybrid/Providers/Google.php:101 Stack 
trace: #0 [internal function]: Hybrid_Providers_Google->getUserProfile() #1 
/var/www/html/test/hybridauth_2.9.1/Hybrid/Provider_Adapter.php(242): 
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #2 
/var/www/html/test/test_hybridauth_original.php(164): 
Hybrid_Provider_Adapter->__call('getUserProfile', Array) #3 
/var/www/html/test/test_hybridauth_original.php(164): 
Hybrid_Provider_Adapter->getUserProfile() #4 {main} thro in 
/var/www/html/test/hybridauth_2.9.1/Hybrid/Providers/Google.php on line 101
```

I went to check the Google developer console, and I think that I found some data fields and tabs there, which might not have existed when I set up the API two years ago. I added everything that seemed to be relevant: Privacy policy URL, Terms of Service URL, and Domain Verification. (My https domain was added into Search Console already two years ago, but now it was missing on tab Domain Verification of Google+ API settings.) I also triple-checked that the key and secret shown in console are (still) the same as I use in my code.

I also tried to play with the scope a bit. Now I use this scope:

"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"

The same error message still persists. I am running out of ideas, what to try next.

Comment: Edit: in fact I am using this scope now:

"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"

Comment: Edit to add: I have also tried with HybridAuth 2.9.1 again, and I get the same error, so this seems to be unrelated to the HybridAuth upgrade. Which is also confirmed by the fact that it functioned for some days after upgrading.